# Difference between polygons

Tags: java, android, polygons

I'm looking for a java library for android or an algorithm description which can calculate the difference between 2 polygons.  I've been looking for a few hours with no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "difference between 2 polygons" ... which means ... ?

Comment: Difference between 2 polygons?  The subtraction?  Pretty standard jargon I thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) library.  It gets tons of use in the Java GIS world, and is generally useful for solving topology problems in Java.  JTS represents various topology types (including Polygons) as with a Geometry base class.  Here's the method for calculating  the difference between two geometries (including two polygons):  http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#difference%28com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry%29

You can download JTS from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/.

Comment: Could you give me a small code example here?  I am completely unfamilar with JTS, and didn't know what GIS was until you mentioned it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The JTS library works on Android.  My only complaint is the execution time in calculating the difference of 2 polygons is rather long.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  It's safe to say JTS hasn't been optimized for mobile environments, although it works great on server and desktop environments.   You may want to try ESRI's Android SDK: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-android/.  I have no experience with it, but looks like the GeometryEngine class could be used to calculate the difference between two polygons.

Comment: Ah thank you, I'll try it.  Do you know if ESRI's Android SDK can also run on Desktop?  I'd like to use one library between desktop and android clients.

Comment: I haven't used any of ESRIs SDKs, but I think they have a heavier API more appropriate for desktop use.   FYI, regarding JTS performance, if you are intersecting a polygon with a layer that contains many polygons (even if the given polygon only intersects one polygon in the layer), you'll benefit from the JTS SPatialIndex.  Spatial indexing won't be worthwhile for a small number of polygons.

Comment: I using this with Box2d for a game.  Box2D has space partitioning for efficient AABB queries, so I shouldn't need spatial indexing.  I appreciate the tip though!

No other library I found could perform polygon difference on Android.  A couple claimed they did, but didn't seem to work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

> The subtraction?

Check out the `Area` API. It has a `subtract()` method.

Comment: I cannot use Area library as its part of the java.awt.geom package which is not present on Android.  I have edited my question, my apologies.